# How to use font-lock-add-keywords inside an ansi-term?

Tags: colors, emacs

I can easily add keywords that I want to highlight to, say, *lisp-interaction-mode*, by doing the following:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-interaction-mode '(("foo" (0 '(font-lock-warning-face)))))
```

This kicks in as soon as I (re)open any buffer in lisp-interaction-mode.

However I can't figure out how to use *font-lock-add-keywords* inside an ansi-term buffer.

I don't know if I get my mode wrong or if there's something "special" about term / ansi-term buffers that would prevent the above from working.

I tried with "term-mode", which is apparently the major mode ansi-term is using, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I use *font-lock-add-keywords* inside an *ansi-term*?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```lisp
(defun highlight-foo ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil ;; putting nil here adds the keywords only to the current buffer
   '(("foo" 0 font-lock-warning-face))))

(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'highlight-foo)
```

However, please note that while `font-lock-mode` is active with such settings, regular ANSI escape sequences won't have any effect on the colors in the terminal (e.g. the output from `ls` will not be colorized).

Comment: font-lock-mode is active and I do have working ANSI escape sequences (e.g. I can see my colored prompt inside my ansi-term) but... The hook ain't working : (    When I turn font lock off for the terminal buffer, then I don't have my colored prompt anymore.

Comment: what happens when you turn `font-lock-mode` back on? (or when you explicitly call `font-lock-fontify-buffer`?)

Comment: In my settings, after I have set the hook up, I can either have `foo` colored when I activate `font-lock-mode` or have ANSI sequences working when I disable `font-lock-mode` (and once ANSI-colorized text has been reverted to B&W by `font-lock-mode`, it doesn't get colorized again later).